# How do I enable the CardDAV server of the calendarserver package?

Tags: server, services, calendar

I installed [the `calendarserver` package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/calendarserver) which provided me with a working instance of the [Darwin Calendar and Contacts Server](http://trac.calendarserver.org/), a CalDAV and CardDAV server.

The CalDAV part seems to be working okay. I can create accounts and share calendars between multiple devices.

I am unable to connect to the CardDAV server to share contacts. How do I enable the CardDAV server of the `calendarserver` package?

I am finding documentation on `calendarserver` very difficult to locate, and what I do find is very outdated.

Answer (score 2):

Drawin Calendar-Server is not actively developed for linux. It still has lots of bugs in Debian stable/testing. You can always file a bug at their respective bug-tacking page or ask for help on Debian/Ubuntu mailing list. For now, Radicale or DAVical works far better.

Find more information here: **https://wiki.ubuntu.com/CalendarServer**